# "Similar Questions" sidebar overlaps the footer

Tags: bug, design

Create a new question and write enough stuff to make the page vertically scrollable. If you scroll to the bottom, the "Similar Questions" sidebar will be overlapping the footer.

For some sites in the network, this is kinda okay. For other sites, it gives me eye cancer.

This is in Mathematics:

[image]

**Info**

Mac OSX, 10.8.5. Google Chrome 34.0.1847.131. Problem seen in Stack Overflow and Mathematics. Probably in all other sites as well.

Comment: Dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105435/similar-questions-pane-visual-bug

Comment: related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9823/

Comment: I'm not sure if this should've been migrated. The issue occurs in all sites - not just Math. It is just *specially* bad in Math.